# derivative of the integral with chain rule applied

Tags: calculus

I'm having difficulty seeing the answer to the following question on one of the practice Calculus MC practice problems:

$$d/dx \left(\int_0^{x^2} \sin(t^3)\,dt\right)= 2x\sin(x^6)$$
The chain rule is applied to the $x^2$ part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FTC, if we denote the antiderivative of $\sin(t^{3})$ by $F(t)$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\sin(t^{3})\mathrm{d}t = F(x^{2}) - F(0)
\end{align*}

Applying the derivative to both sides, we get that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\sin(t^{3})\mathrm{d}t = 2xF'(x^{2}) = 2x\sin((x^{2})^{3}) = 2x\sin(x^{6}) 
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you.  Took me a moment to see that.

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

With FTC $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^{x} f(t)dt= f(x)$ and chain rule:

\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_0^{x^2} \sin(t^3)\,dt\right)= \frac{d}{dx^2} \left(\int_0^{x^2} \sin(t^3)\,dt\right)\times\frac{d x^2}{dx}=\sin(x^2)^3 \times 2x=2x\sin x^6\end{align}